# No matter what i do, i cannot cache my dynamic php files

Tags: php, apache, caching

Ok so, my homepage is relatively slow to load... Well, not really, it takes about a second and a half. Its the slowest page on my site.

Now the thing is, the homepage is 100% static content for that day for users that arnt logged in.

So, i want to make it so if you are not logged in, the content is cached for that day (if they are logged in, then i dont want it cached).

I have been tearing my eyeballs out for the past few hours, cursing every named god and running around with an axe like a lunatic trying to get this to work. I have other parts of the site which currently use caching fine, such as CSS/JS/Images, and all of those, i did really easily and didnt have this issue i have now.

Ill put it blunt... It wont ******* cache...
Im using HTTPS, but i dont see why it wont let me cache the main html file if it lets me cache JS/CSS/Images.

Anyway, so i guess you want to know what ive tried...

Setting cache-control:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Jersey');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$date = date("D, d M Y", strtotime(date("d M Y", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day"));
$udate = date("D, d M Y", strtotime(date("d M Y", strtotime($date)) . " -1 day"));

header('Content-Type: text/html');
header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: " . $udate . " 00:00:01 GMT");
header('Expires: ' . $date . ' 00:00:01 GMT');
```

Sent Headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en-GB
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 11 Sep 2012 00:55:11 GMT
Expires:Wed, 12 Sep 2012 00:00:01 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=75
Last-Modified:Tue, 11 Sep 2012 00:00:01 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Did it cache? No, chrome insisted on every way of loading this page, it would go to the source directly, even if it had been there (while loading images/js/css etc from cache).

So then i tried ETags:

```
function caching_headers ($file, $timestamp) {
    $gmt_mtime = gmdate('r', $timestamp);
    header('ETag: "'.md5($timestamp.$file).'"');
    header('Last-Modified: '.$gmt_mtime);
    header('Cache-Control: public');

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $gmt_mtime || str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) == md5($timestamp.$file)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            exit();
        }
    }
}

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Jersey');

$date = date("D, d M Y") . " 0:0:0 GMT";

caching_headers('homepage', strtotime($date));

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'];
```

Did it cache? No, it would always tell me that HTTP_IF_MODI... is not set

Theres been so many other pieces of code on the internet ive tried, all failed.

What am i missing, there must be a way to cache html files, ive seen loads of sites do it.

Ill explain it very quickly.

My homepage, when the user is not logged in, has static content which changes once a day. This page naturally has the most content in terms of bandwidth size, then any other page on my site.

I want to speed this page up by caching the content if the user is not logged in, and the cache to only last until 0:0:0 the next morning.
Ill need it to be in PHP, and not in the htaccess so i can check if the users is logged in etc.

I believe that i need to use ETAGs, but for whatever reason i can not get them to work. From my understanding this script i use called minify, uses ETAGs fine, and so its not that my server disabled them.

Ill be honest, i dont know what im doing with ETAGs, but there is very limited help (every time theres a thread of someone asking for help the only replies are of someone telling him to disable it.).

[Edit]
Tried a basic cache according to the php documentation:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=604800");
header('Expires: ' . $date . ' 00:00:01 GMT');
```

No dice...

Comment: try to remove last-modified header maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php there are some useful user comments about serving cached content

Comment: Thats not it, i copied one of the examples to enable cache:
[See Edit]

and no dice